# The WiFi ESP8266 modifies my power values in Arduino monitor

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, esp8266

[Here is a link to openenergy monitor where I got the current sensor, you can find the type CT3100.](https://learn.openenergymonitor.org/electricity-monitoring/ct-sensors/installation)

I'm working on an energy monitor using an Arduino Uno. I'm already able to get values (which are correct) of total power in the Arduino monitor. I would like to send that data to a database using an ESP8266 WiFi module.

The problem that occurs is when I add ESP module to Arduino, the values of total power I get in the monitor are not correct anymore.

```cpp
void setup(){  
 wifi.setBootMarker(F("Version:0.9.2.4]\r\n\r\nready"));
 softser.begin(9600); // Soft serial connection to ESP8266
 Serial.begin(9600);;
 emon1.current(1, 55.6);       // Current: input pin, calibration.
 char buffer[50];
 Serial.print(F("Hard reset..."));
 if(!wifi.hardReset()) {
  Serial.println(F("no response from module."));
  for(;;);
 }
 Serial.println(F("OK."));
 Serial.print(F("Soft reset..."));
 if(!wifi.softReset()) {
  Serial.println(F("no response from module."));
  for(;;);
 }
 Serial.println(F("OK."));
 Serial.print(F("Checking firmware version..."));
 wifi.println(F("AT+GMR"));
 if(wifi.readLine(buffer, sizeof(buffer))) {
  Serial.println(buffer);
  wifi.find(); // Discard the 'OK' that follows
 } else {
  Serial.println(F("error"));
 }
 Serial.print(F("Connecting to WiFi..."));
 if(wifi.connectToAP(F(ESP_SSID), F(ESP_PASS))) {
  Serial.print(F("OK\nChecking IP addr..."));
  wifi.println(F("AT+CIFSR"));
  if(wifi.readLine(buffer, sizeof(buffer))) {
   Serial.println(buffer);
   wifi.find(); // Discard the 'OK' that follows
  }
 }
}
void loop(){
 Serial.print(F("Connecting to host..."));
 if(wifi.connectTCP(F(HOST), PORT)) {
  Serial.print(F("OK\nRequesting page..."));
  double Irms = emon1.calcIrms(1480);      //extract Irms into Variable
  double power = Irms*208;
  String data;
  data+="{\"IdClient\":";
  data+=Client_id;
  data+=",\"Nom\":\"";
  data+=Nom;
  data+="\",\"Irms\":";
  data+=Irms; 
  data+=",\"Power\":";
  data+=power;
  data+="}";       
  softser.print(data);
  String Post="POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 13.81.244.50\r\nContent-Type: 
  application/json\r\nContent-Length:";
  Post+=String(data.length());
  Post+="\r\n\r\n";
  Post+=data;
  Post+="\r\n\r\n";  
  String Send = "AT+CIPSEND=";
  Send+=String(Post.length());
  wifi.println(Send); 
  if (wifi.find(F(">"))){
   wifi.print(Post);
  }
  //Test
  if(wifi.find(F("OK"), true)) {
   Serial.println(F("found!"));
  } else {
   Serial.println(F("not found."));
  }
  wifi.closeTCP();
 }   else { // TCP connect failed
  Serial.println(F("D'oh!"));
 }
 delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: hey, what are you using to monitor power? is it an analogue input to the arduino? And is that circuit completely isolated from the es8266?

Comment: thanks to intervent, i'm using a CT(current sensor) to collect current form the load, then i have a circuit on a breadboard that goes to an arduino analogue input...up to that, everything is running well...the esp8266 is correctly connected giving that i'm receiving on "okay" response, i thing both of them are isolated..with the wifi module values are increased

Comment: Whats the load? Is is ma or amps? The analogue pins can be pretty sensitive. Do you have a second arduino to run the esp separately on a different bread board? If its still causing issues its the wifi signal. If not it could be the circuit so you could try using separate breadboard incase one is shorting. Or maybe they're too close together

Comment: the load is a 75w bulb. Now i have tried with a second breadboard and two arduino - nano and uno -, but it does'nt change anything. the values i get range from 100ish to 300ish. without the esp i get the right value. you have to know that the code is different when i use the esp because i add a piece of code to connect to the wifi and post into the database. i can share with you the code if you want. thank you so much or your help

Comment: the code would be helpful to look at, post it in the main question :) what kind of current sensor do you have the terminal screw kind or the clip around an existing wire kind?

Comment: if you could also add some links to the esp8266 module you have and the current sesnor you have i can see if i have the same or similar at home and mock up the same circuit :)

Comment: A sensor is a CT 3100 , it is to clip around an existing wire which in the phase wire of the installation

Comment: ah that kind of current meter can be prone to interference, i think commercial once use low pass filters and such to get accurate readings. could you try separating the esp8266 and the sensor as much as possible using longer wires then gently move the esp8266 closer to the sensor while watching the monitor and if its interference then it should fluctuate

Comment: I just added the code to the initial question, maybe it will help you have more details about the problem. i also added the link for the sensor.  thanks!

Comment: i'm afraid it cant be a problem of intreference because even when i remove the sensor around the wire, i'm still getting high values in the monitor.normally when i remove the sensor, it i'm not suppose to collect values

Comment: doesnt that even more support interference? if wifi is on and no cable through sensor and you still get readings then it could still be interference. do you have longer cables to move the wifi away from sensor, or block the signal somehow to see if the sensor readings change when you do

Comment: Hi Ollie i have tried with longer wire but it does not change. i was suggested to use two arduino codes, one as slave and another as master .the two codes are implemented on differents Arduino cards. So i'll try and let you know whether it works

Comment: Hi, yes as i suggested earlier a separate card would isolate the circuitry to rule that out. Let me know how you get on!

Comment: Hey Ollie, i used a slave code implemented in an Arduino Nano which just calculate the power and send the result to the master. The master consists of a second code implemented in an Arduino Uno which receive the power and send to the database throught the wifi. It is working, i'm getting acceptables values

Comment: Awesome news! So that suggests something in the original circuit isn't isolated properly. What was the pin layout on the original setup? Or better yet do you have a circuit diagram with pin mappings?

Comment: but i have a problem with the way of receiving values. when the value is above 100, (exemple:110.84) there is no problem, but when it is less than 100, i get something like this: 81.82ÿ and it produces an exception.

Comment: are you talking about the first circuit diagram which was not working, or the new one with two arduinos?

Comment: The first one :) and in regards to the below 100 value, id suggest figuring out where it occurs then parsing the value with a function to remove non numeric (or decimal place) characters. if your're getting that returned it could be an issue with the library for the sensor

Comment: Hi Ollie, i've not been working on  my Arduino project  since my last post. But i'm about to continue.Sorry to haven't been able to answer.Anyway, if you want to get more about the circuit diagram with pin mappings, just follow the link on my first post.It it a link to "openenergymonitor" where i got informations for the circuit.Just navigate a bit, it is a complete guide :)

Comment: Hi Nadia :) i was worried you'd given up! I've not been doing much on projects either. I'll read through the site and order the parts myself so i can replicate it at home, it looks pretty useful actually i could use one at home. We will figure this out!

Comment: great just try it and let's see how it works

Comment: all the stuff arrived!!! Im working on it now :) I got the 30A sensor but im sure its the same principal. My email address is in my profile btw if you want to go back and forth quicker and i can send you my schematic when its running, this has to be the longest comment section on stackoverflow haha.